# Boost shared_ptr container question

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

Let's say I have a container (std::vector) of pointers used by a multi-threaded application.  When adding new pointers to the container, the code is protected using a critical section (boost::mutex).  All well and good.  The code should be able to return one of these pointers to a thread for processing, but another separate thread could choose to delete one of these pointers, which might still be in use.  e.g.:

```
thread1()
{
    foo* p = get_pointer();
    ...
    p->do_something();
}

thread2()
{
    foo* p = get_pointer();
    ...
    delete p;
}
```

So thread2 could delete the pointer whilst thread1 is using it.  Nasty.

So instead I want to use a container of Boost shared ptrs. IIRC these pointers will be reference counted, so as long as I return shared ptrs instead of raw pointers, removing one from the container WON'T actually free it until the last use of it goes out of scope.  i.e.

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<foo> > my_vec;

thread1()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<foo> sp = get_ptr[0];
    ...
    sp->do_something();
}

thread2()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<foo> sp = get_ptr[0];
    ...
    my_vec.erase(my_vec.begin());
}

boost::shared_ptr<foo> get_ptr(int index)
{
    lock_my_vec();
    return my_vec[index];
}
```

In the above example, if thread1 gets the pointer before thread2 calls erase, will the object pointed to still be valid?  It won't actually be deleted when thread1 completes? **Note that access to the global vector will be via a critical section.**

I think this is how shared_ptrs work but I need to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the threading safety of boost::shared_ptr you should check [this link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety). It's not guarantied to be safe, but on many platforms it works. Modifying the std::vector is not safe AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

> In the above example, if thread1 gets the pointer before thread2 calls erase, will the object pointed to still be valid? It won't actually be deleted when thread1 completes?

In your example, if thread1 gets the pointer before thread2, then thread2 will have to wait at the beginning of the function (because of the lock).  So, yes, the object pointed to will still be valid.  However, you might want to make sure that my_vec is not empty before accessing its first element.

Answer (score 0):

If in addition, you synchronize the accesses to the vector (as in your original raw pointer proposal), your usage is safe.  Otherwise, you may fall foul of example 4 in the link provided by the other respondent.